# Send File with other Data to springboot backend

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartfile

i'm looking for a solution where i can send at the same time a csv file and other data (angular) to the Spring boot backend.
in my case i cant use a FormData because the data i need to send is not only strings (data are heterogenous) so My DTO in the front looks like something below :

```
export class example {
    id: number;
    addresses?:string[];
    status :string;
    createdBy?: string;
    createdDate?: Date;
    collections : int[]
    addressesDocument: File;    // <------- file i need to send to the backend
    
}
```

in the backend i've created a similar DTO containing a MultipartFile as type for the file
but i got always an exception

```
@PostMapping("/examples")
public void createExample(@Valid @RequestBody ExampleDTO example) throws URISyntaxException, FileNotFoundException {

    System.out.println(exampleDTO.getfile());
          exampleService.create(example);

}
```

**what is the best solution to send a file along with other divers data in the same API ???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send the file as part of the json-object, as indicated in your sample-code. Though it's possible to use content-type `multipart/form-data` and then separately append the file on one hand and the rest of the data on the other hand, to `FormData`.

The Post-request in the Angular-frontend would then look something like this:

```
saveFileAndData(file: File, exampleDataObject: Example) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(exampleDataObject));

    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

    this.http.post('/examples', formData, { headers: headers })
        .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Many thx dude , i already figured it out. it's already working